# EKS minimum permission

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, amazon-iam, amazon-eks, policy

I have a requirement where I have to minimize the permission for EKS cluster in Application perspective and EKS cluster perspective. can anyone help with the list of policy I can attach to the policy document which I will attach to IAM role and link this IAM role to service account of ASG . Or if anyone has any suggestion to do that also welcome.

I checked our terraform code for EKS provisioning and I can see read permission is there . Not sure why my manager still saying to minimize.

Answer (score -1):

AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly: This permission allows EKS to access the Amazon Elastic Container Registry (ECR) for pulling container images.

AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy: This policy grants necessary permissions for worker nodes in the EKS cluster to communicate with the EKS control plane.

AmazonEKSClusterPolicy: It provides permissions for cluster management operations, such as creating and describing clusters.

AmazonEKSServicePolicy: This policy is necessary for managing the EKS service itself, including updates and scaling.

AmazonEKSVPCResourceController: This permission allows EKS to manage networking resources in the Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) associated with the cluster.

Comment: demo-test-eks-cluster-autoscaler [ Role] —>

AmazonEKSClusterAutoscalerPolicy

demo-test-eks-workers [  Role] —>

AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly 
AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy
AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy

AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore
AmazonEKS_EBS_CSI_Driver_Policy [  Customer inline ]

demo-test-eks-cluster[ Role ]—>
AmazonEKSClusterPolicy
AmazonEKSServicePolicy

I have these 3 roles and respective policy attached to my EK cluster. How can I minimize these

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).